# Magento: can not create shipment for orders with an invoice

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

im having problem with creating shipment for some orders programmatically.
for the orders without an invoice, they get dispatched without any problems.

i have pasted my code here, could you please help me to solve this issue.

```
<?php 
 /*
check if orderId is set    
*/
if(isset($orderId)){
$Semail = false;
$includeComment = true;
$shipment = false;


/*
Update order control systems table with tracking 
*/
$dispatchOrder  = $sql->query("update _trackingOrders SET trackingNumber =   '".$trackingNumber."' where order_number = '".$orderId."'");
$dispatchOrderCustomer  = $sql->query("update _trackingCustomer SET orderStatus =  'dispatched' where order_number = '".$orderId."'");
/*
End of updates
   */

if(($dispatchOrder)&&($dispatchOrderCustomer)){

 /*
 Load order by id
 */
 $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);

 /*
 check if order exist
 */
  if (!$order->getId()) {
            echo 'The order no longer exists.';
            return false;
        }
**EDIT:**
    /*
check if order can be invoiced
*/
        if(!$order->canInvoice()){
            echo 'order can not be invoiced';
            return false;
        }
/*
check if order can be ship
*/
    if (!$order->canShip()) {
   echo 'Order can not be shipped';
   return false;
    }
     /*
    * New shipment coding begins here 
    */      
     $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareShipment();

      /*
      **END OF EDIT**
      */
/* 
get all items from the order
*/
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {

if (!$orderItem->getQtyToShip()) {
    continue;
}
if ($orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
    continue;
}

$item = $convertor->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem);

$qty = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();

$item->setQty($qty);
$shipment->addItem($item);
}   



/*
shipment details
*/
$tracking = array();
$tracking['carrier_code'] = 'Royalmail';
$tracking['title'] = $shippingMethod;
$tracking['number'] = $trackingNumber;

/*
add shipment tracking details
*/
$track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')->addData($tracking);
$shipment->addTrack($track);

/*
register current shipment
*/
Mage::register('current_shipment_'.$orderId.'', $shipment);

/*
register shipment
add comment to shipment
send shipment email
*/  
$shipment->register();
$shipment->addComment($comments, $Semail && $includeComment);
$shipment->setEmailSent(true);

/*
set order state as processign
set order is in process
set order status as complete
*/
$shipment->getOrder()->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true);
$shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(false);
$shipment->getOrder()->setStatus('complete');


/*
get shipment order
add statushistory
*/
$_order = $shipment->getOrder();
$_order->addStatusHistoryComment($comments, 'complete')
                ->setIsVisibleOnFront(1)
                ->setIsCustomerNotified(1);
        $_order->sendOrderUpdateEmail('1', $comments);
   $_order->save();


/*
save transactions
*/
$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
->addObject($shipment)
->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
->save();

echo "order has been dispatched";
?>
```

Thanks inadvance.

Jey

Comment: hey guys,

i found one of the problem is that order state can not be set "complete", if the order state is protected.

Stack trace:
#0 app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(673): Mage::throwException('The Order State...')

#1 app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(652): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_setState('complete', true, '', NULL, true)

#2 product_scanning/v2/functions/orderDispatch.php(104): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->setState('complete', true);

But even after i commented out the line, im having same problem.

Comment: Shipment is creating but for some reason order status is not changing and couldnt add any comments to the order.